# Is it possible to push conflicting code to git and let others resolve it?

Tags: git

I am using git to collaborate my work with my colleagues. Our normal workflow is everyone pull the latest code at the beginning of the day and push it back when their parts are done.

However, recently we have a new programmer and she is not familiar with the whole project. Is it possible for her to push (or use any other mechanism) to upload everything she did to the repo and let other programmers to review and resolve the conflicting parts (if present) for her?

Thank you.

Comment: This is what branches are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, she can push her changes to her own branch on the remote server.  Assuming that her changes are on the master branch, she could run a command like this:

```
git push origin master:mybranch
```

That's just one way to do it.  She could also create a non-master branch on her local repository and do her work there and push from there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, she can create a new branch of your code and push that branch to the repository. When you pull the branch and try to merge it into your main branch, you will get a conflict and you'll have to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Github/Bitbucket as your remote repo she can create a new `dev` branch and open a pull request to merge this branch to your `master` branch. If the are conflicts between the `master` and `dev`, Github/Bitbucket will warning you. To solve this issue you can merge your local `dev` to your local `master` branch, fix the conflicts and then reopen the pull request to your remote `master` branch.

Comment: This is an article that explains how Gitflow works: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/centralized-workflow